# how to remove the error type has no constructors defined

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a webpage. But it is giving an error. Please help me. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
   static void myMain()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string data = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(data);

            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
            foreach (HtmlNode link in nodes)
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                Console.WriteLine(att.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is giving error that `The type 'System.Windows.Form.HtmlDocument' has no constructors defined.` I have included HAP.

Thanks

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691657/c-htmldocument-object-has-no-constructor

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
```

to

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

Because you don't want work with `System.Windows.Form.HtmlDocument`